# Delay showing an ad in Admob

Tags: android, admob

I'm wondering if it is possible to delay the showing of an interstitial ad in Admob?
I want to display the ads at natural breaking points in the app, but only after the user has spent 5 minutes using the app.
Does anyone know whether this is possible and/or against AdMob policy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.

First, you load the Ad.

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(/* AD UNIT ID */);
mInterstitialAd.loadAd((new AdRequest.Builder()).build());
```

Then, to show the InterstitialAd:

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

As you can see, you first load the Ad and then you show it. Loading the ad won't add it to the screen.

So, you can invoke `mInterstitialAd.show()` whenever you want (after 5 minutes as you said) to actually display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set as interval your ads with this code

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        Log.i("hello", "world");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                   Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                }

                prepareAd();


            }
        });

    }
}, 20, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, I (you can say that admob)